# .htaccess if request url different from host, redirect to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

When somebody accesses my website `"example.com"` - (this website runs CodeIgniter), I want to be able to detect through .htaccess if that request is NOT `"example.com"`, if someone is accessing my website through `"user1.com"` (this should work as I have my virtual hosts to accept incoming requests if the CNAME is pointed), then they will be redirected to a controller.

This is my attempt at trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/%1$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/site/%1$1 [L,NC,P]
```

If possible, would I be able to keep the external request domain URL, so if the request is from `'user1.com'` it would be fine--basically no masking.

**Site** is the name of my controller and it takes a parameter name.

**Problems**

I think when using this way, the virtual host address doesn't work correctly, it doesn't show sub-pages...

Comment: Is `mod_proxy` enabled and working?

Comment: Yes. I have it working now, but it seems to be masking the URL, how do I keep the original URL that it's coming through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!site/).*)$ http://example.com/site/$1?host=%{HTTP_HOST} [L,NC,P]
```

To remove www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I was using PHP to get the url before: $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; but now since it's a different domain, and it's masked (effectively), this shows my actual domain, is there a way to get the domain that's within the URL bar (in PHP)? Or in .htaccess, use the URL that's being requested and send that as a parameter? Effectively sending %{HTTP_HOST} as a parameter?

Comment: Yes `%{HTTP_HOST}` can be sent as parameter, see update.

Comment: Thanks. I have that working, but what happens if I pass in a page for that particular URL? Can I send that too as PHP doesn't pick it up...

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^((?!site/).*)$ http://example.com/site/$1?host=%{HTTP_HOST}&page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,P]` to also send original URI.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remove www. on all requests?

Comment: You are a genius! I have one last thing, I'm sorry to keep bugging you! I'm also allowing sub-domains, how do I turn www. for sub-domains as well? This works perfect for full domains.

Comment: Above rule will remove `www` for sub domains as well.

Comment: Are you sure? Here's a snippet of my .htaccess and it doesn't seem to remove the www. for subdomains: http://pastebin.com/PGvtPSGR

Comment: Seems I had the positiong wrong on the .htaccess file. Thank you very much for all your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes in general 301 rules should appear before other rules in `.htaccess`.